# Add data from XML to existing SQL Server Database with pre-set parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

This is probably super simple, but I'm new to C# and SQL.  So I have an XML generated by my program like this (it works perfectly).

```
namespace programName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Enumerate all .docx files
            var enumerator = Directory.EnumerateFiles("[file path]"*.docx");

            Xml.checklist xmlList = new Xml.checklist();
            foreach (var entry in enumerator)
            {
             //XML is created
             //name info
             //birthday info
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Now somewhere within this I want to grab the data from the XML and insert it into an SQL server database that already has these pre-existing parameters

```
@nvName (nvarchar(50), Input, Default)
@dteBirthday(datetime, Input, Default)
```

How would I go about doing this within the program? It seems simple, but I'm lost

Comment: You may try to fill the /* do this and that */ parts with some code. How you read docx files? Where data are stored and how? How do you open DB connection? Which part of this workflow doesn't exactly work?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The code with reading .docx files and storing it to xml works.  What I'm confused about is a big picture how to access and add data to a database.

Comment: Create a SqlConnection, open it, prepare SQL statement and put it in a newly created SqlCommand, add parameters (do not build inline sql code) and execute it (non query) and you're done...a quick google search for "SqlConnection insert command example" may help

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but something you might find helpful. SQL has a SQLXML data type. Depending on your circumstance, it might be useful to store directly as XML instead of  parsing. That aside, I encourage you to look at Dapper. It should get you well on your way to reading / writing database from c#.